# array to string conversion warning in foreach loop

Tags: php

[image: error]

I am doing a course on PHP came across for each loop and doing as guided by the instructor, but I am getting this warning while displaying all elements while instructor is not getting warning and the code is same there is no mistake.

Comment: Post code, not images. It is doubtful `the code is same there is no mistake`. The `s` on the `echo` value is likely the mistake.

Comment: yes i should make habit on posting code and thank you

Comment: (Unneeded but an easier way is `foreach(range(22, 88, 11) as $number) {`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output `$number`, not `$numbers`.

```
foreach ($numbers as $number)
{
   echo $number."<br>";
}
```